# Class Cast Exception with Fragment lists and Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtime-error, classcastexception

I'm very inexperienced with java and was nearing the finish of my very first Android app, when my worst fear happened and I reached an error that I have don't know how to interpret.

The basics of the app is 5 lists, selected from a drawer menu. Each list opens up static XML views with contents on it.  All this works in portrait smoothly.  In landscape, the view is a dualpane, with the list on the left, and the contents on the right.  Getting there works fine too.  But I get an error when I go into landscape on one list, then later on try going to landscape on another list.  Can someone please try to help me figure out what is happening?

**Main Activity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    Fragment rotcfraglist = new RotcFragList();
    Fragment afafraglist = new AfaFragList();
    Fragment bmtfraglist = new BmtFragList();
    Fragment docsfraglist = new DocsFragList();
    Fragment extrafraglist = new ExtraFragList();

.... *drawer set up stuff ....

// ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        View fullFrame = findViewById(R.id.full_frame);
        View detailsFrame = findViewById(R.id.details);
        View listFrame = findViewById(R.id.list_frame);

        // Destroy Backstack first
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        ///ROTC
        case 0:
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, rotcfraglist);
            break;
        ///AFA
        case 1:
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, afafraglist);
            break;
        ///BMT
        case 2:
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, bmtfraglist);
            break;
        ///Docs
        case 3:
            ft.remove(rotcfraglist);
            ft.remove(afafraglist);
            ft.remove(bmtfraglist);

            if (detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.full_frame, docsfraglist);
            break;
        ///Extra
        case 4:
            ft.remove(rotcfraglist);
            ft.remove(afafraglist);
            ft.remove(bmtfraglist);

            if (detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.full_frame, extrafraglist);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

**One of the List Fragments**

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BmtFragList extends SherlockListFragment {

boolean mDualPane;
static int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
public final String [] TITLES = {
    "Core Values",
    "AF Mission",
    "Airman's Creed",
    "Air Force Song",
    "Ranks AF Enlisted",
    "Ranks AF Officer",
    "Chain of Command",
    "Reporting Statement",
    "Phonetic Alphabet"
};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.simple_list_item_checkable_1, android.R.id.text1, TITLES));

    // Check landscape or not
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    if (mDualPane) {
        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    showDetails(position);
}

// If landscape, replace details. If not, replace list.
void showDetails(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mCurCheckPosition = position;

    if (mDualPane) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

        BmtDetailsFragment details = (BmtDetailsFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);

        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != position) {
            details = BmtDetailsFragment.newInstance(position);
            ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public static class DetailsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTheme(MainActivity.getThemeId());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            BmtDetailsFragment details = new BmtDetailsFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }
    }
}

public static class BmtDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public static BmtDetailsFragment newInstance(int position) {
        BmtDetailsFragment f = new BmtDetailsFragment();

        // Make index input an argument
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
        return null;
        }

        View newContent = getView();
        int position = getShownIndex();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            newContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.corevalues, container, false);
            break;
        case 1:
            newContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afmission, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            newContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.airmanscreed, container, false);
            break;

    ....more cases.....

        }
        return newContent;
    }
}
}
```

**Main Activity Landscape Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_frame"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_frame" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#262626"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#5C5C5C"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**LogCat**

[image]

Sorry for the wall of code, but I'm really lost here. My guess is it's something to do with the detailsframe next to the list, because the error is pointing at the DetailsActivity in each class which is responsible for setting the contents in that frame.  Maybe I need to clear out the frame before I can load a new list with new details into the same place?  I'm not sure how to go about that though. Any help whatsoever will be greatly appreciated!!! I don't want to see my first app fall apart like this, I feel sick thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution!  Maybe it's not the prettiest, but it works and that's better than crashing.

I determined that each listfragment I had didn't like "sharing" the contents frame in landscape with each other, so I made each list it's own frame layout to put it's fragments into.  When a new list is called, other frame layouts have the visibility set to "GONE" and are essentially put in the background.  When called back later, they show the contents they previously held, which is a good bonus.

Here's the changes in the MainActivity

```
    // ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        View fullFrame = findViewById(R.id.full_frame);
        View detailsFrameRotc = findViewById(R.id.details_rotc);
        View listFrame = findViewById(R.id.list_frame);
        View detailsFrameAfa = findViewById(R.id.details_afa);
        View detailsFrameBmt = findViewById(R.id.details_bmt);

        // Destroy Backstack first
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        ///ROTC
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, rotcfraglist);
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameAfa != null
                    && detailsFrameAfa.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameAfa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameBmt != null
                    && detailsFrameBmt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameBmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameRotc != null
                    && detailsFrameRotc.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrameRotc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        ///AFA
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, afafraglist);
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameRotc != null
                    && detailsFrameRotc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameRotc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameBmt != null
                    && detailsFrameBmt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameBmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameAfa != null
                    && detailsFrameAfa.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrameAfa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        ///BMT
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.list_frame, bmtfraglist);
            ft.remove(docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(extrafraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameAfa != null
                    && detailsFrameAfa.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameAfa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameRotc != null
                    && detailsFrameRotc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameRotc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameBmt != null
                    && detailsFrameBmt.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                detailsFrameBmt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        ///Docs
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.full_frame, docsfraglist);
            ft.remove(rotcfraglist);
            ft.remove(afafraglist);
            ft.remove(bmtfraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameAfa != null
                    && detailsFrameAfa.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameAfa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameBmt != null
                    && detailsFrameBmt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameBmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameRotc != null
                    && detailsFrameRotc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameRotc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            break;
        ///Extra
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.full_frame, extrafraglist);
            ft.remove(rotcfraglist);
            ft.remove(afafraglist);
            ft.remove(bmtfraglist);

            if (fullFrame != null && fullFrame.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                fullFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (listFrame != null && listFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                listFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameAfa != null
                    && detailsFrameAfa.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameAfa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameBmt != null
                    && detailsFrameBmt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameBmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (detailsFrameRotc != null
                    && detailsFrameRotc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                detailsFrameRotc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

And my landscape layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_frame"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_rotc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_frame" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_afa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_frame" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_bmt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_frame" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#262626"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#5C5C5C"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```